# Existence of open map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request

Is there an open map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$? I am guessing that non-existence can be derived from the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not locally homeomorphic, but cannot write down a rigorous argument. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: By "open map" do you mean "open continuous map"?

Comment: @EricWofsey No, just open map.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, compose the following:

1. The [Conway base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, which maps every open interval onto $\mathbb R$
2. A surjection $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$

Comment: Just wow! great trick

Answer (score 4):

Chris Culter's answer shows that there does exist such a map.  However, it is impossible for such a map to be continuous.  Indeed, suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous and open.  Then $U=f((0,1))$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $f([0,1])$ is compact and hence closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  It follows that $U$ is bounded and $f([0,1])$ is its closure, so the boundary of $U$ must be contained in $f(\{0,1\})$.  But any nonempty bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ must contain more than two boundary points (in fact, uncountably many).  For instance, fix any point $p\in U$; then by boundedness of $U$, every line through $p$ must contain at least two boundary points of $U$ (one on each side of $p$).